# Exit Button is not working After Action Listerner

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class StudentGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public StudentGUI() {
        super("StudentGUI Frame");

        //TopPanel
        TopPanel tp;
        tp=new TopPanel();
        Dimension d = new Dimension(800,600);
        tp.setPreferredSize(d);
        this.add (tp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        tp.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);
        setBackground(Color.PINK);
        tp.setVisible(true);
        //TopPanel End

        //BottomPanel
        BottomPanel bp;
        bp=new BottomPanel();
        this.add (bp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        tp.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);
        //BottomPanel End

        //MiddlePanel 
        MiddlePanel mp;
        mp=new MiddlePanel();
        this.add (mp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mp.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(800,600);
        //MiddlePanel End

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    exitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                                    "Do you want to close the window?", 
                                    "Choose", 
                                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
            if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    });

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StudentGUI();
    }
}
```

Here is the code, I am not sure what is wrong, did I miss something? The code executes yet nothing comes..
How do I make the action Listener and action perform execute? It is not realizing the button at all..

Make it so that when the User clicks on the Exit Button, a MessageBox Window popup and ask the User if they are sure that they want to exit.  If they say “Yes”, then Exit the App.

**Bottom Panel:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class BottomPanel extends JPanel {

    public String findbtn="";
    public String insertBtn="";
    public String updateBtn="";
    public String deleteBtn="";
    public String exitBtn="";

    public BottomPanel() {
        JButton findbtn;
        findbtn=new JButton("Find");
        add(findbtn);

        JButton insertBtn;
        insertBtn=new JButton("Insert");
        add(insertBtn);

        JButton updateBtn;
        updateBtn=new JButton("Update");
        add(updateBtn);

        JButton deleteBtn;
        deleteBtn=new JButton("Delete");
        add(deleteBtn);

        JButton exitBtn;
        exitBtn=new JButton("Exit");
        add(exitBtn);
        exitBtn.addActionListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you do with this program, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Could you please indent your code to make it readable (for us **and** for you).

Comment: Oh okay sorry, I want the button to do this:Make it so that when the User clicks on the Exit Button, a MessageBox Window popup and ask the User if they are sure that they want to exit.  If they say “Yes”, then Exit the App.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. And the code is still not indented.

Comment: You might want to include BottomPane

Comment: I also want it to the point where i click on the exit button, it says, are you sure you want to exit? I click yes, it exits, I click no it doesnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ActionListener` basically do nothing, try to move the `JOptionPane` Dialog inside `actionPerform` method.

```
exitBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                              "Do you want to close the window?", 
                              "Choose", 
                              JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 
            if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    System.exit(1);

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I changed it and the program now works, but the exit button doesn't do a thing, what did I do wrong? do I need to add the 

bp.exitBtn.ActionListener; ? If so I tried but It failed to work.

The edited version is now up

Comment: I already answered this in your previous question, you don't have to add it with in the `StudentGUI` by saying `bp.exitBtn.ActionListener` just do exitBtn.ActionListener inside the `BottomPanel` class.

Comment: Just added it in the bottompanel and got a "Actual arguement BottomPanel cannot be converted to action listener"

Comment: No, you have to implement the `actionPerformed` method within a anonymous `ActionListener` class, see my answer.

Comment: @user3741806: What has been said in this answer, you need to do that within the constructor of the `BottomPanel` class, but not outside, by replacing `exitBtn.addActionListener(this)`. Are you sure you know the basics of the language that well?

Comment: Never said I did, complete beginner trying to get help online (:

Comment: @user3741806: I would advice, you to first master the basic concepts of the language, before venturing into `Swing`, that will make life much easier while dealing with `Swing` :-)

Answer (score 2):

check this sample code

```
public class StudentGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton b;
    public StudentGUI() {
        setSize(400, 400);
        b = new JButton("Exit");

        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(b);
        b.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == b) {
            int qq=JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure??");
            if(qq == 0)
                System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new StudentGUI().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Though I am really not the one who downvoted, but might be because of the improper indentation, and not using Swing's `Event Dispatcher Thread - EDT` for creation, or unnecessarily turning to inheritance, when composition alone can do the task. But in the absence of any reason, I can only negate the vote. But still much you need to look in your answer.